# How to merge 3 old existing SKU into 1 new subscription in Play Console?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, play-billing-library

Before we had 3 different SKUs in Play Console for the app. But
with [Recent changes to subscriptions in Play Console](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/12124625) and the Billing Library 5.0, the concept of SKU is considered deprecated.
And the docs say the following:

> "When this functionality launched, any existing subscriptions were
> converted into the new model. The results are:
>
> - Each subscription now has a single base plan with the old    subscription’s billing period. As prepaid plans didn’t exist, these
>   base plans are all auto-renewing.
> - Any free trial or intro price was converted into an offer".

And our 3 old existing SKUs (*SKU A, B, C*) were automatically converted into 3 different subscriptions, each with 1 base plan and 1 offer.
But logically they would be merged into 1 subscription, with 2 base plans and 3 offers:
[image]
So the question is whether we should make changes in Play Console to merge these existing SKUs into 1 subscription (with 2 base plans and 3 offers) or if we can simply treat 3 old existing SKU as 1 new subscription via the new Billing Library 5.0 API without any changes in Play Console. And if we should make changes in Play Console to merge these SKUs into 1 subscription, then how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you won't be able to treat 3 old SKUs as 1 new subscription without any changes. They will be a separate products (`ProductDetails` items).

I'd suggested to leave old SKUs as is for backward compatibility and then to create a new Subscription with base plans and offers. Since implementation of new approach will likely require significant changes.

For example, instead of single `SkuDetails` per SKU with all data on reccurence, price etc. you'll need to work with new `ProductDetails` which will contain list of `SubscriptionOfferDetails`. Where each base plan **and** each offer will be a separate `SubscriptionOfferDetails` item. And each such item will contain 1 or more `PricingPhase` items (depending on offer setup) with all the details on price, duration and recurrence.